# how to add values from file into a dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, optimization, lookup

I have a text file containing integers, e.g.

```
123
456
678
```

I want do read them and put them in a dict, so I later can easily see if an integer was present, e.g.

```
{456: True, 123: True, 678: True}
```

What is the most efficient way to achieve this? I am open to not using dict, if there is some other way I can easily lookup values quickly.

At the moment I am using pandas like this:

```
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, compression='zip')

    mydict={}

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        mydict[row[0]] = True
```

which works, but since the file contain 20 million integers, it takes a while to load it into the dictionary.

Comment: why you need "True" value here and dictionary? You can just use *set*  or any other collection and check if certain integer is  in it.

Answer (score 3):

Well this is not a CSV file, so I don't see why you want to parse it as a CSV.

You can use *dictionary comprehension* here:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    mydict = {int(l): True for l in f}
```

Answer (score 3):

A set might be the most convenient data type here:

```python
myset = set(int(line.strip()) for line in open(filename))
```

And test if an integer was in the file using `in`:

```python
>>> 123 in myset
Out[]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

You can add a column to the dataframe that has True in all rows, then use zip to generate a dictionary as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, compression='zip')
df[1] = True
d = {k: v for k,v in zip(df[0], df[1])}
```

### Option 2

As you are open to suggestions other than using a dictionary, if you already have the dataframe loaded, you can use it to check if an integer is there as follows:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([123,456,678]) 
>>> df
     0
0  123
1  456
2  678
>>> df.values == 123 
array([[ True],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
>>> (df.values == 123).any() 
True
>>>
```

Then in your conditional logic, you can do something like the following:

```
if (df.values == 123).any():  # if 123 is in the dataframe 
   # do something
```